# Can't add button column in asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, servertag

Here is my the code for my gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvPredstave" runat="server" CssClass="gridview" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="even" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
        <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnGetInfo" runat="server"Text="GetInfo" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

When i start my app and try to open this page
I am getting an error in line where is button defined with message:

```
The server tag is not well formed
```

Does anybody know the problem?

P.S. I am using *Visual Studio 2010*

Answer (score 3):

This <s>might be</s> is (I just verified it) your problem:

```
 runat="server"Text="GetInfo"
```

Try changing it to:

```
runat="server" Text="GetInfo"
```

Comment: The autoformat command (Ctrl-K, Ctrl-D) has become my favorite keyboard shortcut because it fixes this issue for me when I forget to add spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Add a space after "server" in `<asp:Button` line:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnGetInfo" runat="server" Text="GetInfo" />
```

You may need set the `CommandArgument` and `CommandName` properties:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnGetInfo" runat="server" Text="GetInfo" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Primary_field") %>' CommandName='GetInfo' />
```